# “Unable to find view” only when not shown on initial page

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.js app with a rather strange issue.

I have a page that breaks if I navigate to it via Ember's router, but not if loaded directly. In this case, `buy/credit_card/index`

If I load `http://localdev/#/buy/credit_card` directly in the browser, the page works fine.

If I load `http://localdev/` in the browser, and then click the couple of links that'll take me to `#/buy/credit_card` very quickly, I'll get these error messages:

> Assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'App.OrderCalculatorView'
>   Assertion failed: You must pass a view to the #view helper, not App.OrderCalculatorView ()
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'proto' of undefined

(The relevant part of) the template for the view in question looks like this:

```
<h3>Pay order with credit card</h3>

<p>Description here</p>

<form>
  {{log App.OrderCalculatorView}}
  {{view App.OrderCalculatorView}}

  <label>
```

The `{{log App.OrderCalculatorView}}` returns undefined whenever this fails.

Definition of `App.OrderCalculatorView` is in the same file as the rest of the app, and placed before the routers – it looks like this:

```
App.OrderCalculatorView = Ember.View.create({
  templateName: 'order/calculator',
});
```

All the JavaScript code for the app is in the same `app.js` file, and all the templates are in the `index.html` file, and they are served as static files (by nginx in this case), so it makes no sense for the view to be undefined in some cases and not in others. Is there any case where `Ember.View.create()` might return `undefined`? Or what else could be an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `extend` rather than `create` your view, ember will create an instance when rendered and it will also destroy that same instance when removed from the DOM. In other words ember will be in charge of the view's lifecycle.

So try this:

```
App.OrderCalculatorView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'order/calculator',
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was it. I can't believe I missed that, thanks :)